# Splitting bullet points followed by text into separate rows in R

Tags: r, regex

I'd like to split bullet points that I currently have in one row into several rows.

"• xxxx • xxx"  should be

"• xxxx"
"• xxx"

I've tried with e.g. `unlist(str_split(df$x, "\\•"))` but to no avail.

Any ideas on how to work with bullet points in R?

Comment: Try `"\\s*(?=•)"` regex (if you are using *stringr* `str_split` function).

Comment: Might be easier to do `str_extract_all("• xxxx • xxx", "• [a-z]+")`

Comment: `unlist(strsplit(x, "\\s*(?=(?!^)•)", perl=TRUE))` should work, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, but doesn't seem to work. Whatever other character I try to put in, all your methods work, as well as the one I mentioned. The result I get is actually nothing - nothing happens, as if the character isn't recognised (the same happens when I try to transform it into something else, e.g. by gsub). I'll keep trying though.

Comment: Try this: `library(stringr);
vals <- "• xxxx • xxx";
Encoding(vals)<- "UTF-8";
df <- data.frame(cbind(unlist(str_extract_all(vals,"([\U{2022}])\\s\\w+" ))));`

Comment: @PKumar, this works, apparently \U{2022} is the right reference. Thanks a lot. Can you perhaps add this to your post and I mark it as helpful afterwards? Since what you mentioned in the post did not, in fact, work on Windows, but the reference provided here did.

Comment: @Psych91 I did put as an answer, Please see it, If it worked for you please accept it.

Comment: @PKumar, sorry, I overlooked it - accepted now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(stringr); 

vals <- "• xxxx • xxx"; 
print(vals)
```

It will return into Octal Escape Sequence as :

```
[1] "\342\200\242 xxxx \342\200\242 xxx"
```

Now, we have to write a regex which can find these ocatal escape sequence.
To do that, I first change the encoding as below

```
Encoding(vals)<- "UTF-8"
```

which when printed will give a value like this:

```
[1] "<U+2022> xxxx <U+2022> xxx"
```

If you do a quick google search, you will find it as a [bullet](http://graphemica.com/%E2%80%A2)

Now, we can write a regex for this utf-8 encoded string and split as per the rules provided in the question like below:

```
df <- setNames(data.frame(cbind(unlist(str_extract_all(vals,"([\U{2022}])\\s\\w+" )))),"X");
```

**Output:**

```
> df
              X
1 <U+2022> xxxx
2  <U+2022> xxx
```

Not a surprise,but bullet can't be seen here as printing the bullet symbol with current local settings so what I did is this, changing the local settings here(please be cautious):

```
oldloc <- Sys.getlocale("LC_CTYPE")
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "en_US.UTF-8")
print(df$X)
```

The Result is this:

```
> print(df)
       X
1 • xxxx
2  • xxx
```

Having given all that above, I can say this still might not work for you for windows machine, but this should work on Mac High Sierra.

To work with windows, I used:

```
library(stringi)
stringi::stri_trans_general(x, "zh")
```

**Output:**

```
stringi::stri_trans_general(df$X, "zh")
[1] "• xxxx" "• xxx"
```

Screenshot for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
A<-as.character("• xxxx • xxx")

B<-unlist(strsplit(A, "•"))[-1]

C<- data.frame(paste0("•",B, sep=""))
```

print(C)
Output is :

```
  paste0......B..sep......
1                  • xxxx 
2                    • xxx
```